# wowlan prevents all sleeping

Tags: power-management, suspend, realtek, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to get my desktop configured to have wake-on-wireless-LAN working. I've turned it on with:

```
> sudo iw phy0 wowlan enable magic-packet
```

and I can confirm that it's enabled:

```
> iw phy phy0 wowlan show
WoWLAN is enabled:
 * wake up on magic packet
```

However, the problem now is that the computer will not sleep at all. If I hit suspend from the Gnome Launcher, or run `sudo pm-suspend`, it goes to sleep and then immediately wakes up. It seems like there's some "false positive" triggering the Wake-On-Lan.

I can confirm that with wowlan disabled, the behaviour does not happen.

I'm wondering:

- Is this a known issue?
- How can I determine what's causing the wake to be immediately triggered?
- Is there a way to fix it?

`lspci` reveals that my network adapter is `Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`. I'm on Ubuntu 19.04. The card itself is a TP-Link Archer T4E.